# Is there a CSS selector for the first sibling of an element's parent?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select the `<p>` element here?
The only constant that I have is the id "Standort".

Any ideas?

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <h2 class="licht"><span id="Standort" class="-sitemap-select-item-selected">Standort</span></h2>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
```

Comment: No such sibling tag in CSS - you need JS for this

Comment: @AIqbalRaj Thanks, how would this look like with JS?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_previous_siblings.asp can help

Comment: As the `Standort` is a child of the `p`'s sibling the `header`, you'll need script. For that to work using CSS alone a parent selector is needed, and today there isn't one.

Comment: I guess this works: header:has(#Standort)+p

Comment: `:has()` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility) in any browser at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```css
header+p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <h2 class="licht"><span id="Standort" class="-sitemap-select-item-selected">Standort</span></h2>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
```

---

If you only can base yourself on the ID of a child element contained in the `header`, there's no pure CSS solution, and you'd have to rely on JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('Standort')
  .closest('header')
  .nextElementSibling
  .style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <h2 class="licht"><span id="Standort" class="-sitemap-select-item-selected">Standort</span></h2>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only need to select the one with id "Standort" - possible?

Comment: That would first require a parent selector in CSS, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Since OP's only known reference is the stated _"The only constant that I have is the id `Standort`"_, you should remove the first part in your answer, as that is wrong.

Comment: @LGSon In that case, the question title needs to be edited.

Comment: No, not necessarily, as you shouldn't base an answer on a title alone, the question's context needs to be read too, where it is stated there is a constraint.

Comment: And as this is a clear dupe question (and the dupe is a good one that have all the workarounds), I don't understand why you don't delete this answer.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen: I edited the title. That was a very misleading title in the first place.

Comment: @LGSon: Not everyone deletes their answers to duplicate questions as soon as they get closed, or at all. I keep my answers to duplicate questions sometimes, when 1) I took the time and effort to write them and did so in good faith for any of a number of reasons, and 2) they provide something specific to the question that may or may not already be covered in the linked question (and are more often than not irrelevant there anyway).